# Is there a simple way to change multiple image sources at once?

Tags: html

I have dozens of HTML files hosted on a platform that is soon being shutdown. 90% of the images within each HTML file are hosted on the dying platform and thus need to be re-hosted.

1. Is there a simple tool or method I can use to bulk download all the
   images within an HTML file, so I can re-upload them to the new
   platform
2. Is there a simple tool or method I can then use to rename all the references to Images in the HTML to reflect the new file path?

Comment: How is the configuration on the server? Do you have a shell access or so?

Comment: No, my access is limited to the options each CMS gives me... very limited. Downloaded the HTML is already a very manual process.

Comment: You can try some webscraping, there are python libraries for that

Comment: JS26 read my answer on this ..... if you are willing to get over initial hesitation of actually installing or running VScode then it would work for you what ever the language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am just going over my head here I am assuming following;

1. you have same domain but changing host servers assumption is you have control over code base. In this case then its simply code over the code and directory structure as its using ftp -> download from one -> ftp upload onto another. hypothetically things should work.
2. you are changing domain so it becomes a programmable issue i.e domain-a.com/someimage.jpg is now domain-b.com/someimage.jpg and it is being fetched by the browser on to which you have no control over.
   if for any reason domain were to be the same and directory structure were to change all you had to do run bit of configuration on ht-access or virtual host or what ever and reroute things internally. ht-access example below

   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule ^somefolder/(.*) otherfolder1/$1

server would identify the URI if it matches the condition then it internally forwards it to otherfolder and /$1 appends what ever was after the matching condition e.g. domain.com/somefolder/myimage.jpg now becomes domain.com/otherfolder/myimage.jpg
BUT domain has to be the same because browser has to send it to the server where htaccess is residing. If its on some other server which is dying then solution is of no use.

Which means we have client side issue. Massive overkill hack so I wont even begin going down  that track.

Easy but takes bit of time and in longer run helps a lot.

1. install vs code - if you haven't used this IDE its about time you should it helps you make better progammingly.
2. make copy of the folder you have where all your code is.
3. run VScode and go to file menu -> open folder
4. on left hand side you see files and structure of the folder meaning folder is successfully opened.
5. once again file menu -> Save Workspace as... prompt will pop up just gave project name or what ever honky doory you like to be. VScode now will configure things for you.

[image]

should be something like this

[image]

if it does not show then simple click the double file icon side pan will toggle.

now that we are done with this lest do the magic
6) click on search icon something similar to this will appear

[image]

little arrow on left gives other options such replace etc
[image]

shortcut Ctrl + Shift + F for search Ctrl + Shift + H for search and replace.

What it does it does not just search in a file it searches in all the files in given folder including sub directories and obviously you can replace them.
[image]

So you need quick dirty way of doing it which is more smarter than actually going over each file one by one then above would suffice.
Other than installing depending upon number of files it should take few second to a minute.
Ps I have quirky way of naming things probably have dozens of temp strings here and there and at times need to change them everywhere. This is what I do.